# Is there a way to prevent users from transfer svn checkout files to another computer or data storage?

Tags: security, svn, encryption

I have a SVN server under CentOS 6.0 and I would like to know if is there a way to prevent users from transfer svn checkout files to another computer or data storage?

Or just similar a encryption mode, readable only in computers that have an key.

Thanks a lot.

Vinicius

Comment: If someone with access to your source code and wants to steal it, they're going to be able to steal it.

Comment: So there is no way to do what I pretending?

Comment: Apply sufficient amount of duct tape on user? :) Otherwise you need to create a seriously locked down computing environment, which goes way beyond the scope of Subversion.

Comment: That's a good option, I will analyze that for sure :) but you know if a version control with this feature exist?

Comment: @deschamps He's saying that you're looking at this from a tool/solution standpoint instead of the process standpoint from which you should be viewing it. There's no one tool that will secure all your systems from everything, and that's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

When you give data to someone you lose control of it. Treat this as an axiom.
The real-world equivalent to your question is `If I give someone my house key is there any way I can stop them from getting into my house`...